# Symmetry group of product polytope

Tags: group-theory, polytopes

The symmetry group of the interval $[-1,1]$ is $\mathbb Z_2$, since it consists only of the identity and the reflection at the origin.

Consider now the square $[-1,1]^2$. Obviously, its symmetry group contains the product $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$, since we reflect the square across the x-axis and the y-axis. But we can additionally rotate the square, so we recognize $\mathbb Z_4$ as an additional factor.

**Question:** How can you calculate the symmetry group of the product of two polytopes from the symmetry group of the factors?

Comment: What would you say is the connection between the symmetry group of the cube $[-1,1]^3=[-1,1]\times [-1,1]^2$ and the symmetry groups of the factors, namely  $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and the dihedral group $\mathbb{D}_8$?

Comment: In any category, the $n$-fold product $X^n$ canonically admits an action by not only $\text{Aut}(X)^n$ but in fact the wreath product $\text{Aut}(X)^n \rtimes S_n$, where $S_n$ acts by permuting the factors. Beyond this I don't know if there's anything general and nice to say.

Comment: The group Qiaochu describes is the full symmetry group in the case $X=[-1,1]$. This is because those symmetries are restrictions of the linear transformations 
$$(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto(\pm x_{\sigma(1)},\pm x_{\sigma(2)},\ldots,\pm x_{\sigma(n)}),$$
where $\sigma\in S_n$ can be any permutation. The reason why this is all you get is that a symmetry of the $n$-cube is fully determined by the images of the standard basis vectors.
These are also called signed permutations. They are generated by certain reflections, and are also known as Weyl groups of type B (or C).